# Automatically Create ClusterRoleBinding on GKE for NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In the [installation guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/) of setting up NGINX Ingress on Google Kubernetes Engine, you have to run the following command to generate a `clusterrolebinding`:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```

Since I'd like to automate the entire setup process I don't want to run this command every time I create a new cluster.

So I want to know if there is a way to create a configuration `.yaml` file which automatically applies the above `clusterrolebinding` to my cluster on GKE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the resulting yaml created by the kubectl command like so:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
  --dry-run
  -o yaml
```

This will give you an output like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: cluster-admin-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: your_user
```

You can then create a yaml file (e.j. `clusterrolebinding.yaml`) with its content and deploy to the cluster as you would with any other config file:

```
kubectl create -f clusterrolebinding.yaml
```

I don't think this is going to be any easier to automate than the `kubectl create clusterrolebinding` command itself though, you still need to tell the cluster about this new binding.

Comment: great! is it possible to read the `name` field from a config map?